# How to Add Rounded Bottom Corners to Drop Down in Foundation 5 Nav

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation 5 and trying to give each drop down menu the top nav rounded bottom corners.

The closest I have come to success is when I tried this:

```
nav.top-bar section.top-bar-section ul.dropdown {
  border: 1px solid $gold;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  a {
    background-color: $gold;
    background-image: none;
  }
}
```

This got me rounded bottom corners but there is a nonrounded square background showing below it. I'm not sure where that's coming from so I don't know what else to try (I've tried a lot of other variations on this).

Here is the HTML:

```
<nav class="top-bar">
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
      <h1><%= link_to (@tour.logo ? image_tag(@tour.logo.thumb('80x60>').url) :@tour.name), tour_path(@tour) %></h1>
    </li>
     <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>
   </ul>
   <section class="top-bar-section">
     <ul class="left">
       <li class="has-dropdown">
        <%= link_to "Tour", '#' %>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><%= link_to "Home", tour_path(@tour) %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "News", "##" %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Rules", "##" %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Forums", "##" %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Signup", "##" %></li>
            <li class="has-dropdown">
                <%= link_to "Seasons", "#" %>
               <ul class="dropdown">
                  <% @tour.seasons.each do |s| %>
                  <li><%= link_to s.short_name, tour_season_path(@tour, s) %></li>
                <% end %>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li><%= link_to "Other Tours", tours_path %></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="right">
        <li></li>
      </ul>
  </section>
</nav>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to consider that the `<li>` tag is also there. You just grabbed the UL from dropdown, which is the "containing" element. However, the `<li>` is also an element here. Could you show us that code as well? Cause we can't define from your little snippet what the true problem is. Plus you might wanna use the `:last child` option as well in your css for your last `<li>` and round those corners too

Comment: Ok I replaced the original (redacted) html I had posted with the actual code from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by removing the border on the ul and moving everything else into the anchor element like so:

```
nav.top-bar section.top-bar-section ul.dropdown li:last-child a {

  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your :

```
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
```

With:

```
border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
```

Comment: That didn't change anything.